# How to physically feel audio

Tags: sound-design, sound

Greets

I have several frequencies between the range of 1-800hz  I would like to find a hand applicator (transducer) where I can play the music and the person would put the hand applicator (transducer) over a part of the body and feel the music.  Does such a thing exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a couple of Vidsonix tactile transducers which are potentially good for this. 
Here's a link:

http://www.vidsonix.com/vidsonixnew/info_vxgh72.htm

And a picture:

[image]

These can be picked up for not too much on ebay here in the UK. You will need to custom build the bit they put their hand on, the transcducer could then screw onto the bottom of it. It is basically a speaker without the cone element.

Comment: And there are more powerful and expensive solutions too - check out Clark Synthesis http://clarksynthesis.com/clark-synthesis-products/tactile-sound-transducers/ for more powerful, high end units.

Comment: very nice idea with Vidsonix tactile transducers also have to try it. Have You got any idea how can I connect it ?

Comment: Yes - it's just the same as a speaker, so you just need an amplifier. Details are on the page linked to in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A speaker will work if you can find one that will play the frequencies you are looking for. Keep in mind that many speakers are made of fragile materials as they are not intended for this kind of use. That being said you could easily damage them by applying to much pressure to them but they will do what you ask. Look at some smaller once made for things like headphones and computer speakers.

You will also need to drive said speaker somehow. This will require an amplifier that is capable of working in this frequency range as well.